# Mysql regexp from 2 characters till 2 characters

Tags: mysql

How can I see the rows which **starts** from ab till cb

```
select * from table where row is regexp '[ab-cb]';
```

but I get all rows which contains the characters ab and cb

thank for help

Comment: Can you add some examples and expected output?

Comment: `a[b-z]|b[a-z]|c[ab]`

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you very much